# WooCommerce MyStile Theme - No Pagination on Category Page

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, pagination, shortcode

I am working on a site that has the WooThemes MyStile theme and runs WooCommerce. For some reason there is no pagination on the shop pages. The shortcode that I am using for these pages is:

```
[product_category category="books" per_page="12" columns="4" orderby="date" order="desc"]
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this solution: https://gist.github.com/klihelp/7810337

In the past, I used to set up product category archives page templates - that was my best workaround. Reading that Github solution, it looks like it would work beautifully... try it out!

Answer (score -1):

to make pagination you should not use shortcode, you can make your shop pages from woocommerce setting

Woocommerce - Product - display (make your shop page)